# How to handle business logic validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Imagine the following scenario:

An entity class "Class" representing classes to be given to students:

```
public class Class
{
   public Term Term { get; set; }
   public string ClassName { get; set; }
   public Subject Subject { get; set; }
   public Staff Tutor { get; set; }
}
```

There are associations with other classes (entities) like "Subject" and "Staff".

Now if we had a ViewModel that includes a list of selectable Subjects and a list of selectable Tutors and those lists are filtered *before assigning them to the view model* according to business rules like the following:

Conditions for creating a Class:

1. Subjects allowed for selection are those that have been created for the current year and don't have more than 2 classes created for them
2. Tutors (Staff) allowed for selection are those that have no more than 3 classes that they are teaching the current "Term"

On the view side, assume we have a Razor view that allows for selections using drop down lists.
Given that it is possible for someone that is logged in to modify form data before posting, they could post data that if directly used for persistence would result in violation of the above conditions.

This brings us to the question of how to handle this:

- Do we validate again on the server by getting filtered lists of "Subjects" and "Tutors" that follow the conditions above and checking that the submitted form contains selections that are compatible with the fetched filtered lists?
- If we do that, wouldn't there be redundancy since we had already done that operation when presenting the view?
- Caching the lists would involve identifying related operations, what if there were conditions *additional to the above 2* affected by actions made by the user when interacting with the views?
- Do rule engines (WF??) fit in this scenario?

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Never trust the data you get back from the client, always re-validate.

Comment: This question belongs on "[/* Programmers */](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)".

Comment: Totally aggree with @artm, people can always change data (also hidden data) by modifying POST / GET request "on the fly". That's why I would re-validate on the server side.